# Toon shader with textures

Tags: c++, opengl-3

I'm trying to implement a toon shader with texture using C++ on opengl 3+ but after a week i only got a color toon shade without textures.

vertex file:

```
#version 330

// Incoming per vertex... position and normal
in vec4 vVertex;
in vec3 vNormal;

smooth out float textureCoordinate;

uniform vec3    vLightPosition;
uniform mat4    mvpMatrix;
uniform mat4    mvMatrix;
uniform mat3    normalMatrix;


void main(void) 
    { 
    // Get surface normal in eye coordinates
    vec3 vEyeNormal = normalMatrix * vNormal;

    // Get vertex position in eye coordinates
    vec4 vPosition4 = mvMatrix * vVertex;
    vec3 vPosition3 = vPosition4.xyz / vPosition4.w;

    // Get vector to light source
    vec3 vLightDir = normalize(vLightPosition - vPosition3);

    // Dot product gives us diffuse intensity
    textureCoordinate = max(0.0, dot(vEyeNormal, vLightDir));

    // Don't forget to transform the geometry!
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vVertex;
    }
```

fragment file:

```
//
#version 330

uniform sampler1D colorTable;
out vec4 vFragColor;

smooth in float textureCoordinate;


void main(void)
   { 
   vFragColor = texture(colorTable, textureCoordinate);
   }
```

can anyone give me a hand to get this shader working with textures ?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another vertex shader input which receives the UV coordinates for each vertex. Forward them to the fragment shader without modifying them directly (using another `smooth out` output).

In the fragment shader, you'd typically do something like this:

```
vFragColor = texture(colorTable, textureCoordinate) 
    * texture(modelTexture, modelTextureCoordinate);
```

.. to achieve the desired effect. Since the 1d texture lookup already gives you the kind of sharp lighting that is typical for toon-ish scenes, adding a texture is just multiplying it's color value with the computed light intensity. It looks best if your texture image are too a bit comic style.

Comment: thx for the answer but what is the modelTexture ? i added in vec4 vTexture0; smooth out vec2 vTexCoords; in main vTexCoords = vTexture0.st; on vertex shadder on frag shadder smooth in vec2 vTexCoords; and  vFragColor = texture(colorTable, textureCoordinate)*texture(?????, vTexCoords); could plz give a working example ? thx